# Fusing motion and color in particle filter

Tags: image-processing, estimation, visual-tracking, particle-filter

I am trying to implement particle filter to track a car bounded by a box.

First i used color histogram as my likelihood function and implemented PF, where i was using the bhattacharya distance to get weights.

Later I used motion technique, In which i am subtracting the  consecutive images, and then finding the contour in the image, which will be the object to be tracked(Camera is static), and I am using the gaussian distribution as the likelihood function to get weights and I have applied PF to it. Now I want to fuse both the techniques in one and use Particle filter .

How can i do it? I tried to search online, But I couldn't find any nice explanation or material.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the assumption that the two observations are independent then the the likelihood function you need is just the product of the two likelihood functions.

If for particle `x`, the likelihood of it in terms of the colour distribution is `p(z_c|x)` and the likelihood of it in terms of the motion contour is `p(z_m|x)` then the likeliood of both observations combined is

```
 p(z|x)
=p(z_c,z_m|x)
=p(z_m|z_c,x)p(z_c|x)
=p(z_c|z_m,x)p(z_m|x)
```

With the assumption of independence this becomes:

```
=p(z_c|x)p(z_m|x)
```

So just calculate the likelihoods as you have been doing and multiply them.

If you would rather not make this assumption then you need to specify `p(z_m|z_c,x)` or `p(z_c|z_m,x)`.